# How to get a date in format "yyyy-mm-dd" from the day of year number and year in Golang?

Tags: date, go

I am trying to format a date in the format "yyyy-mm-dd" using as input the number of the day in year (0 to 365).

As input : 035 and 2021
Output : 2021-02-04

I really don't know if the Go's time library can help doing this simply.

Anyone have any idea of to do it ?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/VT_tCBavtur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean *[day number](https://www.epochconverter.com/daynumbers)*, then that usually goes from 1 to 365 (or 366 for leap year). Because only then day 35 of 2021 corresponds to 2021-02-04.

Just use [`time.Date`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Date), it will convert an out-of-range `day` parameter correctly:

> The month, day, hour, min, sec, and nsec values may be outside their usual ranges and will be normalized during the conversion. For example, October 32 converts to November 1.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    year, day := 2021, 35
    dt := time.Date(year, 1, day, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.Local)
    fmt.Println(dt.Format("2006-01-02"))
}
```

[Live demo](https://play.golang.org/p/Bte4Y7J_rJq)

Prints:

```
2021-02-04
```

If you actually mean day number 0 to 364 (or 365 for leap year), then change `day` to `day+1` like so:

```
    dt := time.Date(year, 1, day+1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.Local)
```

Comment: He actually says `0-365` so accounting for leap years too.

Comment: @StevenPenny my interpretation of the discrepancy was that 0 was a typo (also since [day numbers](https://www.epochconverter.com/daynumbers) normally start at 1). But nice of you to improve your answer with my information.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, it does what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

This does it:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "time"
)

func dayOfYear(year, days int) time.Time {
   return time.Date(year, 1, 1+days, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
}

func main() {
   t := dayOfYear(2021, 35)
   fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Although, your math is off, as 35 days would be February 5, as the year starts
January 1, not January 0.

https://golang.org/pkg/time#Date

Answer (score -1):

This might be what you are looking for, make sure to replace the zone with the zone in which you need the time string to be displayed.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var layout = "2006-01-02"
    zone := time.UTC
    year := 2021
    day  := 35
    
    time := time.Date(year,1,day,0,0,0,0,zone)
    converted := time.Format(layout)
    fmt.Println(converted)
}
```